# using php inside of iframe html tags

Tags: php, html, iframe, request-uri

I am trying to create a website that displays another website in an iframe.

This is my code:

```
<html> 
<title>HTML with PHP</title>
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
}
</style>
<body>
<?php
$page = $_GET['query'];
echo $page;
?>
<iframe align="center" width="100%" height="100%" src="<?=$page;?>" frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When I open the php file off of my website (using a url website.com/file.php?query=https://www.google.com, and look in the inspector, I can see the page that the iframe loaded, but it just shows up as a blank page, not the . I have it up at 
http://www.test.fire-light.tk/web.php?query=url (replace url with any valid url). I am not sure why it shows the blank page.

Comment: what happens when you hardcode the iframe's src? does it load or is it still white?

Comment: Can you try `$page = $_GET['q'];` instead of that thing you're trying with explode?

Comment: When I hardcode the iframe's src, it is still white. When I use `$page = $_GET['q'];` it still shows the correct url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this:

```
<iframe align="center" width="100%" height="100%" src="<?=$page;?>" 
  frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>
```

should be changed into:

```
<iframe align="center" width="100%" height="100%" src="<? echo $page; ?>"  
  frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Iframe you can call PHP file in HTML file . And write your PHP code in test.php  Iframe code `<iframe src="test.php"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<html> 
<title>HTML with PHP</title>
<style>
body {
margin: 0px;
}
</style>
<body>
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = explode('?=', $url);
$page = $parts[1];
echo '<iframe align="center" width="100%" height="100%" src="$page" frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```